# removing verilog inferred latches (incrementing a register)

Tags: verilog

```
always @(state) 
     begin
          case (state)
               zero:
                    rowcounter = 1'b0;
               one:
                    rowcounter = 1'b0;
               two:
                    rowcounter = rowcounter + 1'b0;
               three:
                    rowcounter = rowcounter + 1'b1;
               default:
                    rowcounter = 1'b0;
          endcase
     end
```

Basically, when state = 2, i want the 'rowcounter' to retain its current value, while if state = 3, i want the 'rowcounter' to increment.

I'm having a problem when synthesizing the said code, it says there is inferred latches. I traced the latches and they were located when state is '2' or '3'.  Even though I already set the initial value of 'rowcounter' as zero like below

```
initial
begin
rowcounter <= 1'b0;
end
```

It still infers latches.. What alternatives exist to remove the latches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combinatorial blocks (`always @*`) will infer latches if they hold state. the output of combinatorial logic is generally fully defined by the current input.

In digital logic only **Latches** and **Flip-Flops** can hold state. Since you have not defined a flip flop you have got a latch.

Flip-flops are inferred by using `always @(posedge clk)`, you should also use non-blocking assignments `<=`.

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  case (state)
    zero:  rowcounter <= 1'b0;
    one:   rowcounter <= 1'b0;
    two:   rowcounter <= rowcounter + 1'b0;
    three: rowcounter <= rowcounter + 1'b1;
    default: rowcounter <= 1'b0;
  endcase
end
```

Comment: unfortunately, im trying to follow this (1st always block), http://www.altera.com/support/examples/verilog/ver_statem.html .. I cant replace @(state) with @(posedge clk)

Comment: You **have** to use a latch or a flip-flop to maintain state.